# Migrated question already too old to get attention on target website

Tags: feature-request, questions, migration

When a question is migrated to ServerFault or SuperUser from StackOverflow, it is already `n` minutes old (the number of minutes it took to obtain enough votes for the migration).  This places it well down the stack of unanswered questions, virtually guaranteeing that it will get no attention on the target site.

If we're going to forcibly move an OP's question to another site, shouldn't they at least get another bite at the apple (their question shows up at the top of the stack on the new site)?

Answer (score 12):

Probably a good idea, as migrated questions already have a difficult time for various reasons.

Like orphaned children, unwanted, unloved, they move from foster home to foster home..

EDIT: The premise of this question is in fact incorrect; migrated questions *ARE* bumped to the current date and time on the target site -- and always have been.

Comment: Thanks for the guilt trip. I will never vote to migrate a question again.

Answer (score 1):

It's a lot worse going other direction.  SO front page is only 6 minutes long right now, whereas Serverfault and Superuser are 3 hours long.

Given that questions on the wrong site tend to have poor tags too, migrating to SO is a death sentence.  Are there any numbers on how many migrated questions actually get accepted answers?   I don't think I've seen any get accepted.