# Update the date when a question is migrated

Tags: feature-request, status-bydesign, migration

At the moment, when a question is migrated, it keeps the original date of posting. For example, Ask Ubuntu just migrated [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/151760/22222) question over to Unix & Linux. Note the different "Asked on" and "Migrated on" times:

[image]

The result is that a question that is actually new to the target site appears quite far down the questions page or even (though I don't have an example of this at hand) not on the 1st page of questions at all.

I have found some related questions here, such as [this one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/17716/203101) whose answer suggests that the date should be updated and, most importantly [this one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/27004/203101) where [Jeff's answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/27006/203101) incorrectly claims that the date is actually updated. Since Jeff is fairly familiar with SE, I am guessing that it was updated at some point but that seems to no longer be the case.

So, can we please have the question's date updated upon migration? That will not only help the question get more visibility on its new site, it will also help keep things consistent and give us the information we actually need: how long the question has been *here* as opposed to how long it's been floating around on other sites.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The *last active* date on the question is updated to the migration time, so migrated questions are bumped to the top of the front page that's sorted by recent activity, but they do appear further down the line on `/questions?sort=newest`.

I think this is the most sane outcome we could have. If, say, an older question were to be migrated, it'd be kind of weird to pretend that it was just asked today. Not to mention that we'd either have to adjust every single timestamp (for example, edits, answers, etc) as well or we'd live with with posts or edits that looked like they were made before the question was asked. Either approach would be more confusing than the current behaviour.