# Could migrated questions use the migration date as the "asked" date?

Tags: feature-request, migrated-questions, newest-questions

[This question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/238493/update-the-date-when-a-question-is-migrated) requests that migrations get updated dates to match the time of their migration. That is not the feature I am asking for.

I am asking that, **in the case of migrations**, could the system be changed such that it uses the migration date as the "asked date" so that the question can be found more easily? - Yes, this is a subtle difference but I think it's an important one.

I love the active view. Most of the time it's the only view I use. This is great because I see anything that's active, including recently migrated questions.

I am not the only user on this network (imagine that)... [some users](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3062/what-are-our-thoughts-on-how-elu-is-doing-at-migrating-to-ell?noredirect=1#comment7295_3062) only (or primarily) use the "newest" view. Some of these users are very valuable on a network and it's unfortunate that their primary choice of view means that they never see migrated questions... I'd argue that this also hurts the migrated question's chance of getting a good answer or insightful comments to help improve the question.

Because we use the "asked" date in all cases, these questions could be days and weeks down the list!

Normally, this doesn't matter. Questions are asked, they get their chance at the top of the "newest" list, and then they slowly fade into the past. Migrations are the exception.

---

To address the concerns posed by [Adam](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/155160/adam) in his [answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/238501/284336):

> If, say, an older question were to be migrated, it'd be kind of weird to pretend that it was just asked today.

In this case, we're not changing the asked date, so we're not pretending it was just asked today, we are, however allowing that it was, essentially, just asked today **on this new site**.

> Not to mention that we'd either have to adjust every single timestamp (for example, edits, answers, etc) as well or we'd live with with posts or edits that looked like they were made before the question was asked.

**No timestamps are harmed in the migrating of this question!** That is to say, we're not changing the timestamp of when the question was asked, so there's no incongruity between that and any of the other timestamps, so nothing needs to be changed and there's no confusion created.

Comment: The user already got some tool to re-bump their question and give them visibility, like bounty, and the system already block migration of old  question.

Comment: You've completely missed the point of the request. It's about making the question visible on the new questions page, not about bumping it. Three week old questions can and do get migrated... Why should they be "punished" for being asked on the wrong site by never appearing in the newest questions feed? Most migrated questions are asked by people with insufficient rep to offer bounties.

Comment: 3 weeks's old question migrated ? why it took soo much time to migrate ?

Comment: Apparently someone asked about this on MSO recently. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/382509/a-migrated-question-should-get-its-asked-time-reset